# Lucene .Net Searching with TermVector

Tags: lucene.net

in Lucene.Net,i am creating the document for searching a word and want to display before 10 words and after 10 words.i have used TermVector.

```
Lucene.Net.Documents.Field fldContent =
    new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("content", content,
        Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES,
        Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED,
        Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
```

Can anyone help me how to find out the keyword position and extract nearest 15 words.
please send some code.

Thanks

Ashish

Answer (score 1):

Ashish,
Check out the following link.

http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/

Hitesh.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at Lucene highlighter, it extracts a snippet of text surrounding the query term. This [link](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/HTMLParser/article.html) gives an example.